# Should I use 1 database for posts, configuration, and authentication or split it up?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security

I'm designing a blog-like website system from the ground up, based off of PHP and MySQL. It works based on this structure:

- Everything has a unique ID, known as an entity ID or ENID.

  - A master table contains all ENIDs, so there are no duplicates.
  - There are four types of entities: posts, revisions, modules, and users
  - This is all so that id.php can be asked for any resource on the site and know what to do with it.
- Posts are categorized to a module. For example, documents, messages, events, etc. all belong to a separate module.
- Posts reference a specific row in a revisions table to be displayed to the user.

I'm wondering, would it be best to split the four entities and the master table up across separate databases, or would it be best to keep them all in one? Security is  a TOP priority.

Comment: I recommend you to read a few tutorials on make applications (ie. blog engine, CMS) from ground up. That should help you a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see how splitting those things to separate databases could increase security by itself. It will only complicate your application code without any necessity.

Store them in the same database and focus your security efforts on other areas: firewalls, sql sanitizing, etc.

Keeping authentication information in the same database is absolutely acceptable. Most people do it this way. Just make sure you don't store passwords in plain text (you should store a [salted hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) instead).

Comment: Keeping authentication information in the same database as posts is okay?

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot! I'm kind of a newb, but not new enough not to hash my passwords! :)

Answer (score 2):

I personally think one DB would be enough.

Also, I don't think using more than one DB would increase security in any way, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to store your information in different databases. All of them belongs to one system. Working with different databases will occur you with many tasks and you have to care about many databases instead of one.

You'd better to have just 1 database in this case and focus yourself on its security issues.

By the way, don't forget that you will need relations between key columns for different reason. So At least, working with different databases will force you to do something more that when you have just one database with different tables.

Answer (score 1):

One database should be fine. I usually set things up so that each application/service uses one database, with different table in it for the various information that I want to store.